# why does this simple counter remove the appended div?

Tags: javascript

This simple piece of code works fine:

```
var a = document.createElement("div")
a.setAttribute("id","ici")
a.innerHTML = "5"
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")
b[0].appendChild(a)
var x = parseInt(a.innerHTML,10)

var c = document.createElement("div")
c.innerHTML = "Mon compteur"
a.prepend(c)

a.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (x >= 10) {
    return false;
  }
  a.innerHTML = x + 1; 
  x += 1;
})
```

But when I click the counter, the div in `var c` disappears.

Example is here : [codepen](https://codepen.io/thiebo/pen/XWXZjgv)

Comment: Well... yeah. `c` is a child of `a`, but then you clobber it with `a.innerHTML = ...` I'm not sure what you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the `innerHTML` of `a`. But the element `c` was inside it. And since your overwriting the `innerHTML` you also remove `c`.

Comment: Is what @Niet the Dark Absol said

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry, I did not notice your comment @Niel the Dark Absol

Answer (score 1):

Just replace a.prepend(c) to a.parentNode.insertBefore(c,a).The problem occured because the prepend statement was adding div inside a div.
[image]